# Validating a mathematical model (Lagrange formulation and geometry)

Tags: calculus, geometry, applications

I am working on computing phase diagrams for alloys.  These are
blueprints for a material that show what phase, or combination of
phases, a material will exist in for a range of concentrations and
temperatures (see [this
pdf presentation](http://web.cos.gmu.edu/~tstephe3/talks/SIAMMaterialsScience2010.pdf)).

The crucial step in drawing the boundaries that separate one phase
from another on these diagrams involves minimizing a free energy
function subject to basic physical conservation constraints.  I am
going to leave out the chemistry/physics and hope that we can move forward
with the minimization using Lagrange multipliers.

The free energy that is to be minimized is this:

$\widetilde{G}(x_1, x_2) = f^{(1)}G_{1}(x_1) + f^{(2)}G_{2}(x_2),$

subject to:

$f^{(1)}x_1 + f^{(2)}x_2 = c_1,$

$f^{(1)} + f^{(2)} = 1. $

(and also that the $x_{i} > 0$ and $f^{(i)} > 0$, for $i=1,2$.)

The Lagrange formulation is:

$L(x_1,x_2,f^{(1)},f^{(2)},\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3) =
f^{(1)}G_{1}(x_1) + f^{(2)}G_{2}(x_2)$

$- \lambda_{1}(f^{(1)}x_1 + f^{(2)}x_2 - c_1)$

$- \lambda_{2}(f^{(1)} + f^{(2)} - 1) $

The minimization of $\widetilde{G}$ follows from finding the $x_{i}$'s  that satisfy $\nabla L = 0:$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{1}}   = f^{(1)}G_{1}'(x_1) - \lambda_{1}f^{(1)} = 0$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}     = f^{(2)}G_{2}'(x_2) - \lambda_{1}f^{(2)} = 0$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial f^{(1)}} = G_{1}(x_1) - \lambda_{1}x_{1} - \lambda_2 = 0$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial f^{(2)}} = G_{2}(x_2) - \lambda_{1}x_{2} - \lambda_2 = 0$

which yields:

$(*) f^{(1)}\left[G_{1}'(x_1) - \lambda_1 \right] = 0$

$(**) f^{(2)}\left[G_{2}'(x_2) - \lambda_1 \right]= 0 $

$(\***) G_{1}(x_1) - G_{2}(x_2) = \lambda_1 \left[ x_1 - x_2\right]$

Because $f^{(1)}$ and $f^{(2)}$ are not to be zero, from (*) and (**) we have that

$G_{1}'(x_1) = G_{2}'(x_2) = \lambda_{1}.$

And, a manipulation of equation (***) looks like

$\frac{G_{1}(x_1) -G_{2}(x_2)}{x_1 - x_2} = \lambda_{1}.$

Now, think of $G_{i}$ as an even degree polynomial (which it isn't, but
it's graph sometimes resembles one) in the plane.  Let the points $x_1$
and $x_2$ be locations along the x-axis that lie roughly below the
minima of this curve.  The constraints (*),(**), and (***) describe the
condition that the line drawn between $(x_1,G_{1}(x_1))$ and $(x_2,G_{2}(x_2))$ form a common tangent
to the "wells" of the curve.  It is these points $x_1$ and $x_2$,
which represent concentrations of pure components in our alloy, that
become mapped onto a phase diagram.  It is essentially by repeating this procedure for many
temperatures that we can trace out the boundaries in the desired phase diagram.

**The question is:**  Looking at this from a purely analytic geometry
perspective, **how would one derive the "variational" approach to find a common tangent line that we seem to have found using the above Lagrangian?**  (warning: I don't really know how to
model things using variational methods.)

**And, secondly:** I have presented a model of a binary alloy, meaning
two variables to keep track of representing concentrations.  I have
been working on ternary alloys, where this free energy $\widetilde{G}$
is a function of three variables (two independent: $x_1,x_2,x_3$,
where $x_3 = 1- x_1 - x_2$) and is therefore a surface over a Gibbs
triangle.  Then $\nabla L = 0$ produces partial derivatives that no
longer "speak geometry" to me, although the solution is a common tangent
plane.  (I have attempted to characterize a common tangent plane
based purely in analytic geometry - completely disregarding the
Lagrangian - and have come up with several relations between
directional derivatives... **How might directional derivatives relate
to the optimality conditions set forth by the Lagrangian?**)

**EDIT:**  Thank you Greg Graviton for wading through this sub-optimal notation and pointing out several mistakes in the statement of the problem.  (Also, thank you for the [excellent discussion below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632/validating-a-mathematical-model-lagrange-formulation-and-geometry/1245#1245).)

Comment: yeah the latex, so I'll start by asking are you trying to get help solving a Lagrangian, or do you need help choosing an objective function, or are you trying to understand what an intuitive explanation for why the calculus of variations is finding a extrema? Or something else...?

Comment: I can solve the Lagrangian, and I have the proper objective function, I just don't find it obvious how the solution to the Lagrangian applied to my objective function manifests itself as this *common tangent* between two "wells" on a curve.  When we get to common tangent planes to surfaces, it is even less clear.

Comment: Some of your formulas look fishy to me, I think the constraint $x_1+x_2=1$ shouldn't be there. Also, you dropped the difference between $G_1(x_1)$ and $G_2(x_2)$ when minimizing the Lagrangian, huh?

Comment: Also, the derivative with respect to $x_1$ should read $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2} = f^{(1)}G_1'(x_1) - \lambda_1f^{(1)}$ and similar for $x_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the physical meaning, I take it that $f_1$ and $f_2$ represent the fractions of the two phases in the alloy (this implies $f_1 + f_2 = 1$). I imagine $x_1$ and $x_2$ to correspond to an intensional variable like pressure, whose average $f_1x_1 + f_2x_2 =: \bar x$ is held constant in the experiment. Now, the alloy minimizes the free energy under these constraints.

To **answer** your first question: there is a geometric reason why the solution is the common tangent to $G_1$ and $G_2$ in the case of two dimensions. Namely, the fractions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are exactly the [Barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_%28mathematics%29) of the average $\bar x$ sitting between $x_1$ and $x_2$. In particular, the value of the total energy $\tilde G$ is the height of the line drawn between $(x_1,G_1(x_1))$ and $(x_2,G_2(x_2))$ evaluated at $\bar x$. Here's a sketch:

[image: Free energy of an alloy of two compounds]

From this picture, it is clear that if this line is *not* tangent to both $G_1$ and $G_2$, then you can move it a bit so that the value at $\bar x$ will decrease.

To answer your **second question**, the geometry readily extends to higher dimensions. For instance, for an alloy of three compounds, one has to consider the triangle enclosed by the three points $(x_1,G_1(x_1))$, $(x_2,G_2(x_2))$ and $(x_3,G_3(x_3))$. The situation is a bit degenerate here, any point inside this triangle whose first coordinate is $\bar x$ represents a valid value of $\tilde G$. Of these, nature will choose the smallest one. Consequently, the lower side of the triangle has to be tangent to two of the individual free energies.

[image: alloy of three compounds]

Similar reasoning applies when the variable $x$ is not just a number, but, say, a pair of numbers, then we're dealing with a plane tangent to three individual Gibbs functions.

While not terribly useful in this case, there is also a very general geometric interpretation of the method of Lagrange multipliers. Namely, consider a goal function $f$ and a holonomic constraint $g$. Then, the Euler-Lagrange-equations give $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ which means that $f$ changes only in directions orthogonal to the surface $g$. But since we're confined to the surface $g$, this must be an extremum. Wikipedia has a [picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LagrangeMultipliers2D.svg).

Comment: Thank you Greg. I will post some comments later, gotta get back to work right now!

Comment: You're welcome. :-) I've added a remark on the higher-dimensional case.

Comment: +1 for the hand-drawn figures. :-) (No seriously, your answer is useful.)

Comment: I fixed the errors but I will keep the notation the same so your answer remains consistent with the problem.  The $x$'s represent concentration of the components in the alloy.  Regarding your reply, thank you for pointing out the fact that the $f$'s are barycentric coordinates and describing how minimizing $\widetilde{G}$  results in the common tangent line - especially helpful is considering this interpretation in higher dimensions.